# You're trying to run away from or of my question?

Tags: prepositions

If I ask someone question and he doesn't answer on my question but he's continues to speak about something else. Then what is the way to tell him that he evades my question?

> a) You're trying to run away **from** my question.
>
> b) You're trying to run away **of** my question.

Comment: You run away from questions, just as you run away from an angry grizzly bear.

Comment: This should be easily answered with a dictionary or a [google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22run+away+from%22&oq=%22run+away+from%22). Have you checked?

Comment: Of course, I did. I found both options. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22run+away+from%22&oq=%22run+away+from%22#q=%22run+away+of%22

Comment: "of her own accord" is a set phrase; 'of' is not a preposition taken by 'away'

Answer (score 1):

The correct preposition is **from**.

See [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/run-away):

> When I was 13, I ran away from home.

Or [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/run%20away):

> the child runs away from large dogs

Or [OLAD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/run-away?q=run+away):

> run away | run away from … | run away from somebody